# Print multidimensional array data in a table columns

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I tried a lot all day long but did not get the expected output. I want to print a multidimensional array column ways in HTML table using PHP but when I try to get data column ways, get data row or get data in on column.

```
<?php
$result = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

foreach($result as $row){
    foreach($row as $column){
            echo $column . ",<br>";
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

> get this output:

Volvo
22
18

BMW
15
13

Saab
5
2

Land Rover
17
15

but how can I get this output column 3 array data in 3 column ways as like,
Volvo -- BMW  -- Saab
22    - -  15   - - 5
18   - -   13  - -  2

Comment: The same exact question (exactly the same data) was asked and answered a few weeks ago. It looks like a homework exercise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227604/print-the-contents-of-a-multidimensional-array-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use next idea:

```
$ar[] = array_column($result,0);
$ar[] = array_column($result,1);
$ar[] = array_column($result,2);
```

This step could be optimized as

```
for($i=0;$i<count($result[0]);$i++){
    $ar[] = array_column($result,$i);
}
```

Then do

```
foreach($ar as $col){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$col[0].'</td><td>'.$col[1].'</td><td>'.$col[2].'</td><td>'.$col[3].'</td></tr>';
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/eTImT)

Or with additional `for loop`, optimized:

```
foreach($ar as $col){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($col);$i++){
        echo '<td>'.$col[$i].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/XmQne)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to switch the column index with the row index.  Then loop through as you already were.  So you need to go through all the entries twice.

```
$result = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

$out = array();


foreach($result as $cdx => $col)
{
    foreach($col as $idx => $val)
    {
        // swap the column index with the row index
        $out[$idx][$cdx] = $val;
    }
}

$final = "";

foreach($out as $row)
{

    foreach($row as $col)
    {
        $final .= ($col . ", ");
    }

    $final = substr($final, 0, -2);

    $final .= "\r\n";
}

$final = trim($final);

echo $final;
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/69743eacbdeb5004e05745a8de67b9698996bfdc)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea could be to create the rows and the columns and then use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for the rows and the colums:

```
$columns = [];
$rows = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $column) {
        $key === 0 ? $columns[] = $row[$key] : $rows[$key][] = $row[$key];
    }
}
echo implode("--", $columns) . "<br>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo implode("--", $row) . "<br>";
}
```

Output

```
Volvo--BMW--Saab--Land Rover
22--15--5--17
18--13--2--15
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Z011F)